# WASM with thread support not working on Google Chrome iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, webassembly, emscripten

I have some threaded (pthread) & non-threaded WASM processes running perfectly in several versions of Google Chrome in Android, Mac OS X, Windows, etc across different machines.

I was lucky enough to get hands on an iPhone13 for testing (iOS 15.3, Chrome 97.0.4692.84).
Cross Origin isolation is enabled and SharedArrayBuffer, which is needed for threaded WASM, is supported in this iOS version (https://caniuse.com/sharedarraybuffer).

Unfortunately the WASM code does not run and it stops on the first call to WASM from Javascript.

If i disable USE_PTHREADS on the emscripten compilation then the non threaded WASM works but obviously the threaded one doesn't.

My compilation is done using:

```
emcc -std=c++11 -O3 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s USE_PTHREADS=1 -s PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE=4 -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["getValue"]' -s test.cpp -o test.js
```

Do you have any insight on why (Chrome) on iOS is failing even though there is support for things to run properly? I have some feedback of other people that claim threaded WASM running on iOS so any insight would be helpful.

I can provided barebones/example code if necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone hits this issue:

-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 is the root cause of the issue. For things to work in iOS Safari/Chrome then this flag needs to be disabled -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=0

Comment: Hey do you have any more details on this? Any link/official documentation that supports it?

What I saw is that I had to use the linking flag `-s MAXIMUM_MEMORY=256MB` - which by default would be set to 2GB instead.

It seems that 1GB is also enough for being able to load my application. But when reloading it, it fails with an out of memory error. I believe there's some bug in webkit. Using 256MB I never face such error.

Comment: Hi @RicardPérezdelCampo , yes setting the memory upon compilation using emscripten also works for newer iOS versions. Our application is also ok with a fixed memory size but there are applications out there that don't know...